# Using DynamoDBSaveExpression to evaluate inserting new/updated DDB entries

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

My DynamoDB table looks like this:

```
ID -> String
status -> (READY, DONE, IN_PROGRESS, FAILED)
other attributes..
```

My save data into DDB looks like this:

```
DDBClass class = new DDBClass();
class.setId("ID");
class.setStatus("READY");

DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
Map expectedExpression = new HashMap();
List<AttributeValue> attributeValues = new ArrayList<AttributeValue>();
attributeValues.add(new AttributeValue(WorkStatus.READY.toString()));
attributeValues.add(new AttributeValue(WorkStatus.RUNNING.toString()));
expectedExpression.put(WorkLogDdbItem.WORK_STATUS_ATTR,  new ExpectedAttributeValue().withAttributeValueList(attributeValues).withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.IN));
saveExpression.setExpected(expectedExpression); 
ddbMapper.save(class, expression, DynamoDBMapperConfig.DEFAULT);
```

I want DynamoDBSaveExpression to evaluate such that:
If the entry does not exist, insert into DDB
If the entry does exist, compare the status values and then insert if required. I added `withExists=true` as part of the ExpectedAttributeValue but that gives me an exception:

`Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Exists and ComparisonOperator cannot be used together for Attribute: workStatus (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 3N44TOJ4CFAJQ3A0OSKUCI22ARVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1640)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3443)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3419)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeUpdateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3153)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3128)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:853)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:593)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:732)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:622)`

How do I make this condition with DynamoDBSaveExpression?

Answer (score 0):

By exists, did you mean the record exists already in the table or check for not-null? If its the later, use

```
ExpectedAttributeValue expectedNotNull = new ExpectedAttributeValue()
                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.NOT_NULL);
```

If it is to check if a record already exist in the table, that could be done only on primary key.

AFAIK, DynamoDBSaveExpression on a non-key/non-index attribute could be applied only for updates and not inserts.